# How can I implement apple-touch-icon-precomposed favicons like major websites do?

Tags: html, favicon

According to the Twitter bootstrap documentation, you set the `apple-touch-icon-precomposed` icons and your general favicon as follows:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">
```

This is all fine and dandy, but I can't seem to find any major websites that are actually using these link tags to do this - is there a reason or another way to make the icons available?

I have checked:

- Google
- Bing
- Facebook
- Twitter homepage

Do any of the major websites use apple-touch-icon-precomposed favicons?

If so, where are they / how do they do it? If not, why not?

Comment: Maybe they(Google, Facebook etc.) all have app, and doesn't need to add to home screen?

Comment: Yes apparently the thing to do is to have an app and not use these... Just was hoping to find an example of some major site that did implement them...

Answer (score 1):

If you include them directly under the document root that works too.  We had a problem on our website where Apple was not able to find the icons.  I wasn't involved in that, though, and I just heard about it, but the solution was just to put the icons directly under the document root.

Comment: I tried checking the icon names in the doc root of google and bing and just got 404 errors...

Comment: Well they wouldn't necessarily use them I guess .. only if they needed them.  They may also be named differently than what you have.  For instance, we have `apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png`